# ERROR: Request aborted

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-session

Comencé hacer un pequeño proyecto con node.js, que permite a un usuario registrarse e iniciar sesión, este mismo usuario puede subir imágenes con títulos, donde se le permite editarlas, borrar, actualizar y ver.
Estaba trabajando bien hasta que agregue express-formidable y algo no funcionaba con el path de la imagen que no me dejaba cambiar de ruta. entonces decidí salir del programa y ahora me da este error:

```
    Error: Request aborted
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\node\proyecto\node_modules\formidable\lib\incoming_form.js:122:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:369:20)
    at abortIncoming (node:_http_server:598:9)
    at socketOnClose (node:_http_server:589:3)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:381:22)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:666:12)
```

este es mi archivo principal app.js

```js
var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var User = require('./models/user').User
var app = express()
var cookiesSession = require("cookie-session")
var router_app = require("./routes_app")
var session_middleware = require("./middlewares/session")
var formidable = require("express-formidable")

var methodOverride = require("method-override")
app.use(express.static('public')) 

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(methodOverride("_method"))

app.use(cookiesSession({
    name: "session",
    keys: ["llave-1","llave-2"]
}))

app.use(formidable({keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: true}))

app.set("view engine","jade")

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session.user_id)
    res.render("index")
})

app.get("/signup",function(req,res){
    User.find(function(err,doc){
        console.log(doc)
        res.render("signup")
    }) 
})

app.get("/login",function(req,res){
    res.render("login")
})

app.post("/user",function(req,res){
    var user = new User({email: req.body.email,
                        password: req.body.password,
                        password_confirmation: req.body.password_confirmation,
                        username: req.body.username
                        })
    user.save().then(function(us){
        res.send('Guardamos el usuario exitosamente')
    },function(err){
        console.log(String(err))
        res.send('Hubo un error al guardar los datos')
    })

})

app.post("/sessions",function(req,res){
    console.log("ESTOY AUI EN SESSIONS *********************************")
    User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    },function(err,user){
        req.session.user_id = user._id
        res.redirect("/app")
    })

})

app.use("/app",session_middleware)
app.use("/app",router_app)
app.listen(3000)
```

Tengo muchos archivos así que creo que lo mejor es dejarles mi repositorio a ver que pasa, que estoy haciendo mal.

https://github.com/Susanelizabetth/NODE-proyect.git

Comment: Susana, lamentablemente las preguntas que no muestran un [mcve] terminan cerradas. Si tú misma no puedes crear un [mcve] o aislar la parte de tu propio código que causa problemas, imagina lo que le cuesta a cualquier otro programador. Requiere tiempo de análisis, además de tener que clonar tu repositorio, lo cual implica salir de [es.so], cosa que a muchos no les apetece. Es mejor [edit] tu pregunta y mostrar la parte del código que causa problemas, explicando el error, el resultado obtenido y el esperado. Saludos

Comment: Si, tienes mucha razón @MauricioContreras, va a ser muy tedioso tener que clonar el repositorio y ver linea por linea, pero es que el error que me retorna es como de que aborto la busqueda del usuario y se ve dentro de unas de las librerias node, no veo algo más especifico que me diga que yo tengo algo mal estructurado.

Comment: Entonces tengo muchisimos archivos, y como el error no dice en donde de ellos pasa, hay que ver los todos, incluso e investigado aparte y tiene que ver con el bodyParser, pero aun no se exactamente en que parte. Te mostare mi app.js que es el index